# Android Room - RawQuery not working to update/insert data in the DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using room library version 1.1.1 for database operation. I succeeded to create a table in the room but not able to insert/update data in it. Cursor giving me 0 value after performing the raw query but I can not see data in the DB.

While executing the code room even not giving me an exception but when I perform simple insert query, it's working fine.

The query simply says if we have **chatDialogId** in the **Notifications** table then update the message count or if it is not available just add a new raw with message count 1.

Thanks in advance

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Notifications")
public class Notifications {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "chatDialogId")
    private String chatDialogId;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "messageCount")
    private int messageCount;

    public Notifications() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getChatDialogId() {
        return chatDialogId;
    }

    public void setChatDialogId(String chatDialogId) {
        this.chatDialogId = chatDialogId;
    }


    public int getMessageCount() {
        return messageCount;
    }

    public void setMessageCount(int messageCount) {
        this.messageCount = messageCount;
    }

}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface SMDatabaseDao {

    @RawQuery
    public long insertUpdateNotificationCount(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
}
```

Calling below method from **FCMIntentService** while received a message.

```
public Long insertUpdateNotificationCount(final String id) {
    return runInTransaction(new Callable<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            String customQuery = "UPDATE Notifications SET messageCount=messageCount+1 WHERE chatDialogId='" + id + "' AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Notifications WHERE chatDialogId='" + id + "'); " +
                    "INSERT into Notifications(chatDialogId,messageCount) SELECT '" + id + "', 1 WHERE not EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Notifications WHERE chatDialogId='" + id + "');";

            return smDatabaseDao().insertUpdateNotificationCount(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(customQuery));


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says:

> RawQuery methods can only be used for reading queries. For write queries, use
> `RoomDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().`

Here is a link to read the full document.
[@RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery)

Comment: If you are using Flow and a RawQuery insert/update you will also want to call, 
`RoomDatabase.getInvalidationTracker().notifyObserversByTableNames("this_table","that_table")`. Otherwise the `Flow` wont produce new information for its observers. Only catch is its a "RestrictedApi", but I wasn't able to find an alternative.